# How to use Spring MVC with Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Or I'm doing smth wrong, or it's really not suitable to work together. I'm talking about nested entities, since almost each Hibernate entity has it.

Here's the simple entity:

```
@Entity
...
public class Car implements Serializable {
String name;
@ManyToOne Category category;
...
}
```

And the simple controller as well:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars/add",         method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void add(Car car) {
    // persist the car here
}
```

Now I want to specify a category directly from the form. Since it isn't simple object but entity, I'm unable to do that, isn't it?

So, to specify the category seems I'm forced to send it separately from Car object... It's ugly approach that makes no sense to use Hibernate with Spring at all.

Or I'm wrong and there're ways better a lot?

Comment: Usually, in your controller, you dont accept a ready made entity. Instead, you accept data elements, and then you construct the entity within controller or with a help of DAO. In your controller, you have method like `addCar(String carBrand, String carType, int seatCount, String categoryId)`. Then inside the controller body, you construct the car, obtain the category, set the category into the car, and call a DAO to persist your car.

Comment: If he is passing around JSON data, I think it's ok to use POJO and let Spring do the mapping with a @RequestBody annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your form structure is?
I suggest you to use json(means @RequestBody in controller) to submit the form or use @CommandObj to submit the form